# Is there are any alternative to recaptcha in WSO2 Authentication Server?

Tags: authentication, wso2, single-sign-on, recaptcha, wso2-identity-server

Ws02 Authentication Server Use  Google's Recaptcha captcha. 
Is there any alternative instead of Google's Recaptcha which can be used without an Internet connection, on Ws02 Authentication Server?

Answer (score 0):

Identity Server OOB only supports reCaptcha. However you can write a custom captcha implementation by implementing CaptchaConnector[1] to support offline captcha. Please check [2] for reCaptcha implementation.

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/captcha/connector/CaptchaConnector.java

[2] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/captcha/connector/recaptcha/PasswordRecoveryReCaptchaConnector.java